# Strange watermark on a iPhone photo taken in Target

Tags: iphone, photos, privacy

My friend recently took a photo with iPhone 5 in Target's changing room and a watermark automatically applied over it saying "You look goooood. #UniversalThread #TargetStyle". 
It wasn't written on the mirror, it's clearly watermarked on the photo after the capture.

How did Target even do that? It raises some serious privacy issues. Data/wifi was off during the taking of the picture and the stock camera app was used. I found zero info about it online.

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: This does not seem possible. Can you give any more information about it? It's not possible for something like that to just appear.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about Apple hardware or software, as described in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @fsb - How is this not about Apple hardware given that the photo was taken on an iPhone?  Voting to "Leave Open"

Comment: @Allan I read the question as asking how Target puts words on a mirror that you can't see when looking at it but shows up in pictures.  How's this about anything related to Apple?  OP could've taken the picture with an Android device and received the same image.

Comment: @fsb - the OP's lack of understanding how the technology  works doesn't negate the underlying fact as to why this isn't off topic - it was taken on an iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

I would be willing to bet that Target is using hidden watermarks that are only visible when taking a photo (similar to the [watermark that is used by banks to protect checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-evident_document)).  What I hypothesize they are using is a [fluorescent dyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_printing#Fluorescent_dyes) that only shows up under certain lighting conditions (like the high intensity led of a smartphone camera flash)

See:  [Invisible glass watermarks will ensure your new watch or smartphone is genuine](https://www.geek.com/tech/invisible-glass-watermarks-will-ensure-your-new-watch-or-smartphone-is-genuine-1659936/)

Out of sheer curiosity, I would do a simple test: take a compact mirror into the restroom with you.  With your phone in Airplane Mode, take a picture of the bathroom mirror and of the mirror you brought in.  If the image is in both places, it's "tech" related.  If not, it's in the mirror.

Comment: The text is clearly printed on the mirror, as you can see it is at an angle. I would recommend doing the double mirror test as well.

Comment: You could also just hold your hand between the iPhone and the mirror. If the watermark is hacked into the iPhone somehow (unlikely,) then  the watermark will overlay the hand. If the watermark is actually part of the mirror then the watermark will be obscured. No fancy mirrors or airplane mode needed.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this is probably embedded in the mirror and only shows up in pics. Couldn't find anything on the web.